# R: update left data table from right data table

Tags: r

I have two data tables:

```
library(data.tables)

dt1 <- data.table(A = letters[1:5], X = 1:5)
   A X
1: a 1
2: b 2
3: c 3
4: d 4
5: e 5

dt2 <- data.table(A = c("a", "c", "e"), X = 9:11)
   A  X
1: a  9
2: c 10
3: e 11
```

All I want to do is update dt1 based on dt2. I tried:

```
merge(dt1, dt2, all.x = T, by = "A")
   A X.x X.y
1: a   1   9
2: b   2  NA
3: c   3  10
4: d   4  NA
5: e   5  11
```

But it creates a two new variables (`X.x`, `X.y`) while the original want disappears (`X`). This is the output I am looking for:

```
   A  X
1: a  9
2: b  2
3: c 10
4: d  4
5: e 11
```

What would be the shortest syntax? I have to run this process several times.

Comment: I don't think there's a `library(data.tables)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table` `join` syntax, with the update method `:=` (here `i.X` is the `X` variable from `dt2`, use it to update `dt1`'s `X` variable where their column `A` matches):

```
dt1[dt2, X := i.X, on = .(A)]
dt1
#   A  X
#1: a  9
#2: b  2
#3: c 10
#4: d  4
#5: e 11
```